# How can I preload images in a Worker?

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, worker

I try to preload a image in a worker：

```
var img = new Image();
```

That will got an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Image is not defined.

Are there other ways to preload images in a worker? XMLHttpRequest is can do that?

If so when I use the XMLHttpRequest in worker to preload images, my main ui thread will cache that images?

should I use Image or XMLHttpRequest in my main ui thread?

Answer (score 3):

With Web Workers, you do not have access to the DOM in the same manner as you would with JavaScript running in the context of the page. Web workers run in their own context, but that does not mean you cannot pre-load images, you just have to do it a different way. For example:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.responseType = 'blob';
x.onload = function () {
    //Do something
}
x.open('GET', url, true);
x.send();
```